# MongoDB .NET - Binding data to model classes but unable to read Integer value

Tags: c#, mongodb, model, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection called "transaction" like this

```
{
    "approverSpv": {
        "id": 176,
        "isApproved": true
    },
    "approverManager": {
        "id": 176,
        "isApproved": true
    }
}
```

And I want to read those Approver's `id`.
Here are my classes:

```
public class ApproverManager
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool isApproved { get; set; }
}


public class ApproverSpv
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool isApproved { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction() 
{
     public ApproverSpv approverSpv { get; set; }
    
     public ApproverManager approverManager { get; set; }
}
```

And then I tried this code from C#:

```
var transactionParts = database.GetCollection<Transaction>("transaction").AsQueryable<Transaction>().ToList();
```

The code returned always shows 0 to every `id` inside `ApproverSpv` and `ApproverManager` but successfully gets the actual value of `isApproved`: `true` or `false`.

May I know, what did I miss here? How to get the actual value of each `id` inside the `Approver`?

Comment: If you decorate it with `[BsonElement("id")]`, does it make a difference?

Comment: Apply `[BsonNoId]` attribute to the top of  `ApproverSpv` and `ApproverManager` classes. By default, the property with `Id` will mapped to `_id` in MongoDB.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it still the same @ProgrammingLlama.

Comment: Thank you @Yong it works! Please put it in the answer section so that I can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the property name: `Id` is treated and mapped to `_id` in MongoDB .NET. To prevent the default deserialization, you should apply the [`BsonNoId`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes_BsonNoIdAttribute.htm) attribute to your classes.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

[BsonNoId]
public class ApproverManager
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool isApproved { get; set; }

}

[BsonNoId]
public class ApproverSpv
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool isApproved { get; set; }
}
```